# Bash function with formatting

Tags: bash, unix, bash-function

I'm using the following in my .bashrc file as a function to grep info from an external LDAP but would love for it to output a couple of values, but each on their own line

```
function ldaps() { ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://ldap-server.example.com -b ou=People,dc=exampe,dc=com uid=$1 | grep uidNumber: ; }
```

Ideally, it'd output something like:

```
% ldaps jsixpack
uidNumber: 9255
loginShell: /bin/bash
displayName: Joe Sixpack
```

Stuff like that.

Ideas, suggestions appreciated!

Comment: What's the raw output from the ldap query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-E` flag with grep for extended regex:

```
function ldaps() {
  ldapsearch -x -H ldaps://ldap-server.example.com -b\
  ou=People,dc=example,dc=com uid=$1 |
  grep -E '(uidNumber|displayName|loginShell):'
}
```

This will return matches of either `uidNumber`, `displayName` or `loginShell` each that are followed by a `:`.

Hope this helps